# Proof of a statement about infinite collection of closed sets with empty intersection

Tags: general-topology

How do you *formally* prove this: if a collection of closed sets in a compact space have empty intersection, the union of their complements forms an open cover.

If the collection is finite, then the statement (which becomes if an only if) seems obvious (and I wonder if we have to prove it if the collection is not finite) and I don't think compactness is required but I put it in anyway since the source (Katok and Hasselblatt) had it in the proof of:

> A collection of compact sets with the finite intersection property has nonempty intersection

where finite intersection property means that every finite subcollection has nonempty intersection.

Once this statement in question is proved, the claim above follows by contradiction, since a closed subset of a compact set is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\bigcap_{\alpha}U_{\alpha}=\varnothing\\\left(\bigcap_{\alpha}U_{\alpha}\right)^c=\varnothing^c\\\bigcup U_{\alpha}^c=X$$
where $X$ is the whole space.

Comment: Thanks, I need to look up the proof of De Morgan's laws in the uncountable case.

Comment: @nishaChandramoorthy de Morgan is just (for any number of sets) using $\lnot (\forall x \phi(x)) \leftrightarrow (\exists x \lnot \phi(x)$

Answer (score 1):

I'll denote the closed sets by $F_i$ ($i \in I$). Let $x \in X$. Then $x \notin \cap_i F_i$, because the intersection is empty. By the definition of intersection this means that there is some $i$ such that $x \notin F_i$ (otherwise it *would* have been in this intersection). But then $x \in X\setminus F_i$. As $x$ was arbitrary, the complements of the $F_i$ cover $X$.